# How to disable anything from happening when closing the lid of my laptop on fedora 37

Tags: linux, laptop, fedora

It really bothers me because I use an external monitor when I'm home but when I close the lid the network connection drops. I've tried adding these lines to my /etc/systemd/logind.conf

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```

And I've tried changing the settings in the gnome-control software

Comment: 1) does the laptop otherwise continue running, i.e. does not suspend? 2) does the system log (journalctl) have any mention of the disconnection? 3) is the laptop on Wi-Fi, and if so, does the same happen with Ethernet connections or an external (USB) Wi-Fi dongle?

Comment: @user1686 The laptop does not suspend and the connection is still there but it becomes really slow (I tried making speedtests with the lid open and closed). The laptop is on wifi but I didn't try using an ethernet cable because I don't have one now.

Comment: the connection is still there but it becomes really slow   ....   The wifi antenna is in the lid and that is likely why the problem. It is not related to "Lid Close do Nothing"

Comment: Compare the output of `iw wlan0 link` with the lid open and with it closed? Does `iw event` output anything when you close the lid?

Answer (score 1):

Two hardware changes to fix issue:

1. You can check WiFi signal strength with a tool such as Nirsoft's free [WifiInfoView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html). If signal strength and quality drop significantly with lid closed, connect a piece of wire of about the same length in place of the antenna for the WiFi card, and extend it out the back, or, if you do not want to take apart the laptop, **use an external WiFi USB adapter**, e.g., [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BMY8TXC6).
2. If the issue is due to the lid switch, either disconnect it or put small switch in series.

Had you provided info on the laptop, you might get a more specific answer.